# Switch Activity in a Camera.PictureCallback

Tags: android, android-activity, camera, android-camera

I have a Camera.PictureCallback function that gets called when the camera takes a photo in android, but I am wondering how I can access the Activity that the camera is part of. Here is my code:

```
public Camera camera = null;    

Camera.PictureCallback pictureCallbackJpeg = new Camera.PictureCallback()
{ 
    //PictureCallback(Activity a)
    //{
    //    
    //}
    // An attempt at creating a constructor...

    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera c)
    {
        camera.startPreview();

        // would like to call activity method
    }
}

// Camera Initilisation

camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallbackJpeg);
```

I would like to switch activities and also call a method my main activity here, but I cannot work out how I would do this. Any ideas?

Comment: can't you can pass your main activity as a parameter to that class?

Comment: I tried, but it didn't let me. I am new to Java so I may have done it wrong, but I tried creating this method: `PictureCallback(Activity a)` but it didn't let me saying that the method should have a return type.

Comment: you sure can't do that, can you post your full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the methods/functionality that needed to be called in different classes & put them in some thing like AndroidUtils.java. You could then call the common method from the Activity class ***and*** the Camera.PictureCallback.

It just is cleaner that way & you don't have to pass an object to another just to call the common method.